# ServiceStack RequiredRole is resetting my expiry (time to live) to 2 weeks

Tags: c#, authorization, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack with Redis to store sessions. Session expiry is set on a per user basis. It's all is working well expect for these specific service methods, which are having a side effect of changing the TTL (Time to live) back to the default of 2 weeks when I use `[RequiredRole(Roles.Admin)]`, but just using `[Authenticate]` isn't any problem.

```
using Repositories.DTO;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Auth;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationService : RegisterService
    {
        private readonly RegistrationRepo _repo;

        public RegistrationService(RegistrationRepo repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        [Authenticate] // No problems
        public object Put(RegistrationRequest registration)
        {
            var result = _repo.UpdateUser(registration.user);

            return new
            {
                user = result
            };
        }

        [Authenticate]
        [RequiredRole(Roles.Admin)] //Problems. Expiry resets to 2 weeks
        public object Post(RegistrationRequest registration)
        {
            var result = _repo.UpdateUser(registration.user);

            return new
            {
                user = result
            };
        }
```

I initially set the `SessionExpiry` in the `OnAuthenticated` of an custom `CredentialsAuthProvider` class, and don't manually change the `SessionExpiry` any other place in the app (no [sliding session expirations](http://teadriven.me.uk/2013/02/14/sliding-sessions-in-service-stack/) at this time - pun intended).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the Session is saved it's saved again with the default Session Expiry which you can specify on the top-level `AuthFeature.SessionExpiry` for temp Sessions or `AuthFeature.PermanentSessionExpiry` for permanent (Remember Me) Sessions.

You can also intercept each time a Session is saved and change what Session Expiry it's saved with by overriding `OnSaveSession` in your AppHost:

```
public override void OnSaveSession(
    IRequest httpReq, IAuthSession session, TimeSpan? expiresIn = null)
{
    var customExpiry = ...
    base.OnSaveSession(httpReq, session, customExpiry);
}
```